# Datacontext Object Type for LINQ results

Tags: c#, linq

Suppose have two class

```
Class A
{
  var a,b,c;
}
Class X
{
   var x,y,z;
}
```

I perform a join for a list's ItemsSource,

```
(from A in a1 join X in x1 on A.a equals X.x select new {A.b, A.c, X.y, X.z}
```

I now want to retrieve the datacontext from the List on Clicking a button

```
var v = (Button)sender.DataContext as ???
```

I would imagine that the DataContext should have a class as the following as generated by the LINQ operation

```
Class ???
{
  var b,c,y,z;
}
```

Can anyone help on a way to retrieve data from this LINQ generated class
so I can access

```
v.b
v.c
v.y
v.z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the dynamic type e.g.

```js
var v = (Button)sender.DataContext as dynamic;

//Then access the values as v.b, e.t.c
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating anonymous object in your LINQ query, just use some object defined by yourself.

```
public class MyData
{
    public int b { get; set; }
    public int c { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public int z { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
from A in a1 
join X in x1 on A.a equals X.x 
select new MyData()
{
    b = A.b, 
    c = A.c, 
    y = X.y, 
    z = X.z
}
```

Also note, that you can't create `class` where properties are declared like `var prop { get; set; }`. You can use keyword `var` only when declaring local variable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... Although this works... I'm using many combos of data and I don't want to keep creating various combinations of classes for each join... The Above "dynamic" class makes it simple.

Comment: @funjinman I'm glad you found an answer that serves you the most :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the anonymous object incorrectly.

```
select new {A.b, A.c, X.y, X.z}
```

should be written

```
select new {b=A.b, c=A.c, y=X.y, z=X.z}
```

instead, then you can access the properties using v.b,v.c etc.

The object you created (if it worked at all) created empty properties named 'A.b', 'A.c', 'X.y', and 'X.z'